# Algorithm to chase (kinda) unknown point in graph

Tags: python, algorithm, graph

I'm working on a simulator where providers create offers that are bought by consumers.

- Providers put offers on a Price (y-axis) x Quality (x-axis) plane.
- Consumers only buy offers with lower price and higher quality than their preference
- Consumers buy the offers with the highest Euclidean distance.
- Consumers can only buy one offer.
- The provider does not know the exact position of the consumer. It does **know a region** where the consumer is located and it does know the **distance** to the consumer.

I need to implement an algorithm for the provider to update their offers and improve its utility.

To illustrate the issue, here's a illustration:

```
 P ^         .
   |         .
   |   C     .
   |     \   .
   |      \  .
   |       \ .
   |........ P
   |
   |
   |
   +---------------------> Q
```

The Provider (`P`) knows where it placed the offer, so it knows that the Consumer (`C`) must be inside the dotted area.

I came up with a couple algorithms to approach the consumer.

1. The Provider increases price and reduces quality by one unit (moving towards the point `(1, 0)`). The issue with this approach is that when the Consumer is along one of the axis of the dotted region, the Provider quickly loses its sale, as the its offer will no longer satisfy the consumer.
2. Move by half of the distance to the consumer in the direction of the point `(1, 0)`. This can reach the consumer faster, but arrives at the same issue as before (when the consumer is along the dotted area axis).

Are there other algorithms out there that I am not aware of? Is there a Python module for this? (`:)` there are modules for almost everything nowadays)

Comment: I can almost guarantee there is no python module for this.

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far? Take a look at this article to understand how to take the best out of StackOverflow https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If the Consumer is along an axis, is there *any* movement that won't cause failure?

Comment: I'm a bit confused... First of all if the distance is Euclidean you can calculate the location of the consumer after one move (using circles and a bit of geometry). Second of all, why would you want to get closer to the consumer if it will buy the offers with the highest distance? And lastly you are setting a set of rules that match multiagent system but creating an algorithm for single provider and consumer...

Comment: There's a marketplace that decides which offers are valid (meet consumers needs) and which offers will be bought. The marketplace calculates the Euclidean distance and assigns the best offer to the consumer

Answer (score 0):

at your first guess (x0,y0) (P on your schema) and given d (for the given euclidean distance from C to P).
Offer (xc,yc) lies in the circle of center (x0,y0) and radius d.

```
  +
  |
  |          XXXXXX
  |        XXX
  |      XC
  |     X
  |    X
  |   X
  |   X            P0
  |
  |
+-+---------------------------------+
```

if you select (x0, y0+e) e the smallest you "can", (xc,yc) also lies on the circle of center (x0, y0+e) and radius d2
so C lies on the intersection of both circles

```
  +
  |              XXX
  |           XXXXXX
  |        XXXX
  |      XXCX
  |     X X
  |    X X         P1
  |   X
  |   X            P0
  |
  |
+-+---------------------------------+
```

you can then just solve the system:

```
sqrt((xc-x0)^2 + (yc-y0)^2) = d^2
sqrt((xc-x1)^2 + (yc-y1)^2) = d2^2
```

here with x1==x0 you'd get

```
d^2 - (yc-y0)^2 = d2^2 - (yc-y1)^2
```

which is simple to resolve (variable being yc)

then you select the yc such that `y_0<y_c` and get back xc such that `0<x_c< x_0`.

Problem simplifies as:
you just need to get "lucky" on the second guess in order for the bounding box to still globes C.

if you move eps on x axis what are the odds to invalidate C, same for y axis. Depends if your provider tend to give themselves some margin on quality or price...